# How to clone or create a nested DOM node and change all its containing id values according to a current id?

Tags: javascript, dom, domparser, template-literals, clonenode

I need to display some numbers, strings from a class named Student, but i can't figure it out how i can change the id from children element. I have to use JavaScript.

what i tried to do:

```
class Student{
    static count = 0;
    constructor(nume, prenume, data_nasterii, foaie_matricola){
        this.IdClasa = ++Student.count;
        //definirea atributelor
        this.nume = nume; 
        this.prenume = prenume;
        this.data_nasterii = data_nasterii;
        this.foaie_matricola = foaie_matricola;
    }
    afiseazaVarsta(){
    
    }
    afiseazaNotele(){
        
    }
    calculeazaMedia(){
        
    }
    adaugaNota(nota_noua){
        
    }
}
var Stud = [new Student("Name", "Name1", "2000.01.01", "0123123"), 
            new Student("Green", "Blue", "2022/12.12", "321321")];

function afisareStudenti(){
    let i = 0; let bol = false;
    for(let x=1; x<=Student.count; x++) {
        console.log(document.getElementById("AfisareStudenti"+x)==null);
        if(document.getElementById("AfisareStudenti"+x)==null)
        {
            i = x;
            bol = true;
            break;
        } else {
            bol = false;
        }
            
    }
    

    if((i<=Student.count)&&(bol==true)){
        for(i; i<=Student.count; i++) {
            console.log("i="+i);
            var div = document.querySelector('#AfisareStudenti1');
            var divClone = div.cloneNode(true);
            console.log(divClone);
            divClone.id = 'AfisareStudenti'+(i);
            div.after(divClone);
            var NumeStud = document.getElementById("NumeStudent"+(i-1));
            var PrenumeStud = document.getElementById("PrenumeStudent"+(i-1));
            var dataNastStud = document.getElementById("intData"+(i-1));
            var FoaiaMatStud = document.getElementById("FoaiaMatStud"+(i-1));
            NumeStud.id = "NumeStudent"+(i);
            PrenumeStud.id = "PrenumeStud"+(i);
            dataNastStud.id = "intData"+(i);
            FoaiaMatStud.id = "FoaiaMatStud"+(i);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the html file(the div that i want to clone):

```
<!--AFISARE-->
<div id="AfisareStudenti1">
    <h2> Afisare Student 1</h2>
    <label>Ce student doriti sa modificati?&emsp;</label>
    <form>
          <label>Nume:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="NumeStudent1"><br>
          
          <label>Prenume:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="PrenumeStudent1"><br>
          
          <label>Data Nasterii:</label><br>
          <input type="date" id="intData1"><br>
          
          <label>Foaie matricola:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="FoaiaMatStud1"><br><br>
          
          <input class="butoane" type="submit" value="Afisare"
                 onclick="afisareMeniuAfisStudenti()">
    </form>
</div>
```

the class is saved in a dynamic array (could be n object of the class) so i have to make somehow to display the information dynamic. My version changes the id from all elements with the same id (every incrementation of i, the idnumber from id is incremented also). I tried to create that div with document.createElement but is impossible(at least for me) xD . I started coding in javascript 2 days ago, so please take it slow on me :(

I think i found the problem, but it doesn't solve it. (i need to put (i-1) when calling for getting the ids). (Newbie mistake)

Comment: Question ... what are the values (`'AfisareStudenti1'`, `'AfisareStudenti2'`, ...) of the `id` attributes good for anyhow? If possible, the OP should get rid of it. It makes the cloning process less complicated as well. In case the reason was querying student items. One could go with a generic class name like `'student-item'` where one could access the node list of student items like ... `document.querySelectorAll('.student-item')`... and access each student item by it's index (`0`, `1`, `2`, ...).

Comment: I'll use that to hide the div. I don't know if it's reliable to hide them one by one :) And for me it was easier to copy the whole div. At least, for me.

Comment: still no need for an `id` ... one can access each student item via its node list index in order to hide it.

Comment: i try to understand what you said there... Node list? It's returning an array of indexes?  I know how to code in java, c++ but javascript seems to be very different...

Comment: Have a look again into my 1st comment and then into a documentation e.g. [MDN Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) and there into [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) ... e.g. hiding the first student item node ... `const listOfStudentItems = document.querySelectorAll('.student-item'); listOfStudentItems[0].style.display = 'none';`

Comment: The OP is not showing the entire code ... e.g. what does the global function `afisareMeniuAfisStudenti` (`displayStudentsMenu`) do? How does it get the correct/current student item's info/data. Also, who is in charge of calling the function `afisareStudenti` (`displayStudents`)? I have the feeling that if provided with the broader picture the audience could be of much more help since the OP could be provided back with leaner/cleaner and better maintainable approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having commented ...

> *"I have the feeling that if provided with the broader picture the audience could be of much more help since the OP could be provided back with leaner/cleaner and better maintainable approaches."*

... I nevertheless hereby lately provide **a template-based approach which**, besides supporting the OP's `id` based querying of student-items, **is also easier to read and to maintain**.

The code provided within the example-code's `main` function does not just implement the usage of the template-based node-creation via [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [`DOMParser.parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) but also [prevents the default behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) of each student-form's submit-button by making use of [event-delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

```js
function createStudentElement(studentId) {
  const markup =
    `<div class="student-item" id="AfisareStudenti${ studentId }">
      <h2> Afisare Student ${ studentId }</h2>
      <label>Ce student doriti sa modificati?&emsp;</label>
      <form>
        <label>Nume:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="NumeStudent${ studentId }"><br>

        <label>Prenume:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="PrenumeStudent${ studentId }"><br>

        <label>Data Nasterii:</label><br>
        <input type="date" id="intData${ studentId }"><br>

        <label>Foaie matricola:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="FoaiaMatStud${ studentId }"><br><br>

        <input
          class="butoane" type="submit" value="Afisare"
          onclick="afisareMeniuAfisStudenti(${ studentId })"
        >
      </form>
    </div>`;

  const doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(markup, 'text/html');

  return doc.body.removeChild(doc.body.firstElementChild);
}

// the button click handler.
function afisareMeniuAfisStudenti(studentId) {
  console.log({ studentId })
}


function main() {
  const itemsRoot = document.querySelector('.student-items');

  // - prevent any form-submit by making use of event-delegation.
  itemsRoot.addEventListener('submit', evt => evt.preventDefault());

  // - just for demonstration purpose ...
  //   ... create student-items from a list of student IDs.
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(studentId =>
    itemsRoot.appendChild(
      createStudentElement(studentId)
    )
  );
}

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 50%; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="student-items"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the `id` attribute of children elements, you could use [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) on `divClone`.

Because if you use [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [`Document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) you will get the first element that matches your selector (i.e.children of `div#AfisareStudenti1`).

```js
let i = 2;
var div = document.querySelector('#AfisareStudenti1');
var divClone = div.cloneNode(true);
divClone.id = 'AfisareStudenti'+(i);
divClone.querySelector("h2").innerText = "Afisare Student " + i;
var NumeStud = divClone.querySelector("#NumeStudent1");
var PrenumeStud = divClone.querySelector("#PrenumeStudent1");
var dataNastStud = divClone.querySelector("#intData1");
var FoaiaMatStud = divClone.querySelector("#FoaiaMatStud1");
NumeStud.id = "NumeStudent"+(i);
PrenumeStud.id = "PrenumeStud"+(i);
dataNastStud.id = "intData"+(i);
FoaiaMatStud.id = "FoaiaMatStud"+(i);
div.after(divClone);
```

```html
<div id="AfisareStudenti1">
  <h2> Afisare Student 1</h2>
  <label>Ce student doriti sa modificati?&emsp;</label>
  <form>
    <label>Nume:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="NumeStudent1" /><br>
    <label>Prenume:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="PrenumeStudent1" /><br>
    <label>Data Nasterii:</label><br>
    <input type="date" id="intData1" /><br>
    <label>Foaie matricola:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="FoaiaMatStud1" /><br><br>
    <input class="butoane" type="submit" value="Afisare" onclick="afisareMeniuAfisStudenti()" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the code... it seems to work just fine with 2 objects... But if i add more than 2 i get this error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'id')```  on this line ```NumeStud.id = "NumeStudent"+(i); ```

Comment: @AmicuLL Yes, my bad, I edited my answer. You clone `div#AfisareStudenti1` every time. When `i` is `3`, `divClone.querySelector("#NumeStudent2");` is `null`.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's kinda straight forward how it should be done :)) . At first i though that java scripts create the elements instant (it's in a for loop, yeah... i'm stupid) and when the code starts changing id, it's changing all of them (the code behave like this at first and i could not tell why :P)